# ¿como consumir web api por mvc de manera Sincronica?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, asp.net-web-api

Necesito consumir una web api a través de un proyecto mvc de manera sincrono , sin embargo la mayoría de los ejemplos son asincronicos,

Tengo El Siguiente Codigo:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Buscar(int? id)
    {
        //Get
        var vm = new VM_Prov();
        VM_Proveedores v = new VM_Proveedores();
        if (id.HasValue)
        {


            string apiUrl = "http://localhost:61698/Proveedor/Buscador?id=" + id;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));



                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    v = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VM_Proveedores>(data);
                    return View("Proveedores", v);
                }

            }
        }
        return View("Index", vm);
    }
```

¿ Existe Alguna Manera de realizarlo de Manera Sincronica?

Comment: Por que necesitas hacerlo de forma sincrona?

Comment: En serio no es buena idea forzar operaciones asíncronas a ejecutarse bloqueando (síncronamente).  Tal vez si comentas por que necesitas hacer esto te podamos ofrecer una alternativa.

Comment: Es por la peticion de un cliente.  Me  pidieron que consuma una api rest de manera sincroníca por el hecho de que no están acostumbrados a trabajar de manera asincroníca.

Comment: lo que plantras no es un problema del servidor sino del cliente como consume el servicio, con que codigo realizas la llamada desde el cliente? usas la clase WebClient o HttpClient